# When must you use poor design to finish a project?

Tags: deadlines

There are many different bad practices, such as memory leaks, that are easy to slip into a program on accident. Sometimes, they might even be able to jury-rig your program together.

I'm working on a project right now and it works if I deliberately put a memory leak in my code. If I take the leak out, the code crashes. Obviously this is bad, and needs to be (and will be) fixed soon.

My question is, when do you decide to deliver code in this state, if it's not possible to release code without these poor practices, in time?

Comment: Are you mixing new[] and delete, or new and free?  Or freeing the memory using a pointer which wasn't returned by new/new[]/malloc/calloc/realloc?  Make sure you're fixing the leak PROPERLY.  =]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the problem's impact on actual usage of the system can be reasonably expected to be none or negligible, and the delivery date cannot be pushed back, and it can be fixed within a scope of time before the problem's impact becomes more than negligible, ship it.

Obviously this is not ideal or even recommended, but you're clearly pushed into a corner at this point. Sometimes there are no good choices, but pragmatism must win over formal correctness. If an application has a memory leak, but we can reasonably expect that the app will be recycled or machine restarted or whatever before the leak becomes a real problem, that can sometimes be better than delivering late. It depends on the conditions of the agreement and the customer.

It's always better to at least *try* to push back the delivery date, but I am assuming you've already tried that and it's not an option here.

It is typical once an application has been shipped to ignore [technical debt](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TechnicalDebt.html) and move on. It's the responsibility of the developers to clearly communicate to the stakeholders the importance of paying off some of that debt, especially in a case like this.

However, given that it seems the customer cares more about a delivery date than correctness, it's less likely anyone will be convinced to pay off any debt once you go live. This is a bad situation to be in. Only the person with all the facts can make the right choice.

Comment: Well Windows was full of leaks until just a few years ago, so its not an unheard of plan I guess.

Comment: @Robert yeah, though I'm reluctant to use Windows as an example for anything any of us ever do. That is in its own category and has requirements and considerations different from any other software.

Comment: @Rex M: the poster says the code crashes. So that is not neglible impact.

Comment: @Mitch the poster says the code crashes *without* the code that is causing the memory leak. The question is whether shipping with an obvious memory leak is ok, given the alternative.

Comment: @Rex M: Read the question: "If I take the leak out, the code crashes."

Comment: @Mitch exactly? The asker has a choice between two problems. One is the memory leak, so the question is whether the impact of the memory leak is acceptable, given that the alternative (crashing) is obviously not.

Answer (score 6):

> My question is, when do you decide to deliver code in this state, if it's not possible to release code without these poor practices, in time?

Never.

What you do instead: prioritize and focus.

If what you're working on is really high-priority, and you've mis-designed it, something low- priority has to be sacrificed.  Often, some feature(s) must be delayed to give you time to focus on the high priority feature that doesn't work.

If what you're working on is really low-priority, you have to ask why you're not working on something higher-priority.  And you still have to focus and prioritize.  Sometimes things which are very low priority must be sacrificed.

When you can't do "everything" you have to pick things you *can* do that will be reasonably bug-free.

Comment: Voted you up to negate the downvote.  I don't see why this is being downvoted.

Comment: Many people consider that the schedule is "sacred", and bad code is acceptable because the schedule is more important than the working feature set.

Comment: There is no such thing as good code. 3+ year old code will always look bad. There will always be a newer library, a newer language feature, etc. Few companies are actually able to have technical debt. It helps if you do not have much of competition, and the business folks at your company are good ex-programmers who care.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in the concept of [technical debt](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TechnicalDebt.html).

Comment: Quite a buzz word these days. What I want to know is: what are some realistic strategies for repaying this debt efficiently?

Answer (score 2):

You only have three knobs you can turn when shipping software, assuming a fixed number of developers: features, quality and ship date, and turning one up means the others get turned down.

One of the most difficult things to do in software development is to build your product with the knobs set just right.  For example, the Duke Nukem Forever guys have turned the features and quality knob up to eleven and thrown the ship date knob out the window.  Microsoft often seems to glue the ship date knob in place and turn down the feature knob as needed, then unglue the ship date knob, turn it up a bit, glue it back down and continue twiddling the other two.  And there are seem to be an endless amount of products out there that ship all the time but never put in the features they need to be successful.

In the end, you don't get paid if you don't deliver.  Having poor quality hurts you terribly in the long run; reputations are hard to rebuild.  It has almost always been that the right thing to do is to cut features if you have too many bugs.  Always.

However, bug triage is just as important as feature development.  What kind of leak are we talking about here?  Are you leaking a byte?  A small object? One thousand objects?  Entire DLLs?  There are scenarios where its probably better to leak a little than to fail to deliver the product.

And what do you mean by leak?  Does your application have a well defined life cycle?  Where you allocate something once at startup and then never free it until the process dies?  Well how long does your process run?  Do you expect to run multiple copies of your process?

Obviously you never *want* to leak, and you should work to develop best practices that minimize leaking, but in the end you have to make a judgment call.  Maybe you can just explain the bug to your customers, explain the impact, and they'll buy it anyway.  Maybe you can patch it a week later.  Maybe you really do need to fix it.  But we'd need to know more about it to give good advice.

I will say I have shipped known leaks in the past.  I won't say what product or company, but I had a bug where DLL dependencies and insane lifetime management made it next to impossible to correctly free our references to a certain DLL once it was loaded, so in the end we just leaked it.  And I still think it was the right thing to do.  Other times I've seen things deliberately leaked to keep third party code that was written incorrectly from crashing (though that is a completely separate debate).

But in the end I believe such instances are rare and once you have identified the source of a memory leak, it shouldn't take much more than a day to fix it.  It is rare indeed that I would ship with a memory leak that was known and a fix was known.  It would have to be something that required a major re-architect involving changing a threading model, or refactoring huge swaths of code, and it would literally have to be a day or two before the product was to ship.  At that point I might just leak the memory and promise a patch in a weak after proper testing could be done on the re-architect.

Comment: Sometimes you can get more developers, but they will not be able to help right away.

Answer (score 1):

I would be very uncomfortable releasing with such a known bug. It is likely to occur in another way.

You have not specified your environment or language, but I suggest you look at using a memory checking tool such as:

[Purify](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/purify/) (trial available)

[BoundsChecker](http://www.compuware.com/products/devpartner/visualc.htm)

[Valgrind](http://www.cprogramming.com/debugging/valgrind.html)

or even a free one, [Visual Leak Detector](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/visualleakdetector.aspx)

Comment: I use this one, Visual Leak Detector, its great enough :)

Comment: Valgrind is free (and great!  Does more than just memory leak checking).

Comment: Well I meant a memory leak just as an example, not necessarily a specific case.

Comment: @samoz: the question makes it seem like you have a specific case of memory leaks/problems.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, when you are not going to be around to maintain the code later, you don't care about your client/employer and none of the ramifications of your code could possibly affect you.

In other words, in your professional coding life, it's never a really *good* idea.

If you are working for someone that is less concerned about code quality than you are and simply wants you to finish the code at all costs, then I can see how you'd be in a difficult situation.  Finishing faster but poorer will earn you some immediate reward.  You should remember though that even if failing to meet your employer/client's expectation for a milestone bites you only once, your poor code may continue to bite you into the future, not only through the difficulties in maintaining it but also through the negative impression others may form of you down the track.

Answer (score 0):

If its a single (or limited) memory leak, and it doesn't grow, and say it only causes a crash when shutting down (the most common case of stuff like this), then it depends. If its a client/desktop software and the users are going to crash every time on their way out, I'd make it an ultra high priority. If its server, and the only one running the server is you, and everything else works fine, I'd say its alright to enter beta. But if the leaks grow, or can cause crashes at "random" times they need to be fixed asap.

Answer (score 0):

To get past an internal milestone, it's arguable, although still nothing to be taken likely.

To release, never. It always comes back and bites you. If your software is in such a bad space that a piece of poor design will get it over the line, you've got *much* bigger problems looming round the corner

Answer (score 0):

**Never**, unless you don't care about the poor developer who is going to be maintaining your work afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, a decision like this should be made by the customer or the project manager.  Individual developers should not be making these kinds of decisions alone, or keeping this information to themselves.

Tell them what the problem is, and what the consequences will be for not fixing it.  If they want you to ship it broken on time, that's their call.

If you don't want to work for people who accept shoddy products, that's your call, but it's a mistake to think that developers have some sort of professional responsibility to ignore their clients' and bosses' quality/cost/time priorities.

If somebody may actually die if you ship bad software, then don't do it, but if the worst-case scenario is that somebody is going to have to reboot a couple times per day, then do what you're told or find another job.